# Spring Security doesn't remember authenticated users

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring-security with a Spring-MVC application. Currently I am able to login user, password hashing and all is working beautifully. Whenever I need the authenticated person object, I retrieve the name via Spring security, then by accessing database I get the user object. All good till there. Now when I load the application first time, I log in, I close the tab, and I again give the application address, I would like to check if the user is authenticated and redirect. This is where I am having problem. I went through many tutorials on net, and I am almost doing the same. Kindly have a look at what I am doing wrong. Thank you for your time.

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
            boolean id = isAuthenticated();  // Here I am calling the function I have written to see if I am logged in
        if(id){
            return "redirect:/canvas/list";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
            model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
            model.addAttribute("notices",new Notes());
            model.addAttribute("canvases",new Canvas());
            return "person";
        }
    }
```

isAuthenticatedFunction :

```
private boolean isAuthenticated(){
        Authentication authentication =   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authentication == null){ return false;}
        if(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Security-application-context.xml

```
 <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <!-- Global Security settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http pattern="/" security="none" />
    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/canvas/list" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"  />
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/canvas/list" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />

    <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
    </security:port-mappings>

    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" invalid-session-url="/invalidSession.html">
       <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="3" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/sessionExpired.html"/>
    </security:session-management>

    </security:http>
    <!-- queries to be run on data -->
    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="key" value="_spring_security_remember_me" />
        <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Database management for remember-me -->
    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
           <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
               <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

To retrieve logged in user, I am using the method mentioned below, which works like a charm right now.

```
 @Override
    public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authentication == null){
            System.out.println("User is not authenticated");
            return null;
        } else {
            Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(authentication.getName());
            return person;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I was manage to solve it by removing this <security:http pattern="/" security="none" /> and using the getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() method for checking.

Comment: If you use `security="none"` then no filters are applied and it is as if Spring Security doesn't exist for requests to that URL. So you won't be able to access any security data during the request.

Comment: Oh, that is why it was not passing any data around. So, the one i did is the optimal solution, right?

Comment: It depends. Currently you are only securing the exact path "/canvas/list". Anything else will have no security so it works. In most apps you would want to have a secure-by-default approach where you add a wildcard "/**" and whitelist specific URLs that you want to access. If you do that you'd have to explicitly add anonymous access for "/".

Comment: I have other URL's which need secure access, but the functions in Service Layer check if the user is authenticated or not by asking for ROLE_USER. I have no intercept-url or anything for /. Is that correct?

Comment: If you're confident your service layer is secure, then yes, that's OK.

Comment: Oh yes, the service layer, and even the DAO's are secured, and any operation first checks if the user is authenticated by the method given above, then only the user is allowed.